How is this a shopping question?
The question here is IMO a clear design question with meaningful text and sketches.
How to make a SR latch that reacts to edges on its inputs?
Still it was closed as a shopping question. Even the reopen decision went in favor of leaving it locked.
Isn't this this wrong judgement to put it bluntly?
If the closure is warranted then the description of the "shopping" close reason should be adjusted to reflect what is the issue.

The original wording is fairly easy to understand as looking for parts, so the close reason is applicable:

What is an IC that allows connection on one signal and off on another?
I was wondering if there is an IC or combination of logic ICs that do the function...

What's inappropriate, however, is that this situation is easily cured.
This is a legal term: https://dictionary.findlaw.com/definition/cure.html

to deal with in a way that eliminates or corrects: to use judicial procedures to undo [potentially damaging procedural error]; ... 
to correct or make acceptable a defective performance or delivery under a contract...

It seems in this case, voters took the lazy way out and closed it first.
Sometimes, a reasonably equivalent question is not evident from the original, and it must be closed for the OP to make suitable edits.  Preferably, comments would be added to kindly emphasize which part(s) are at issue.
Comments are especially helpful for the more unusual/tenuous/stretched rules we have here (like how asking for references, even though no transaction is implied, is considered under the "shopping" umbrella).
In this case, a readily acceptable question can be interpreted from the original post, which seems in spirit of what was intended; it is curable.  The edits that were later performed, followed this route.
I've seen several questions before, in such a state -- perhaps the source-asking part is merely a final sentence, easily removed, and yet the question has already received a close vote and no edits.  This is something I think reviewers could do better on.  Remember that there are more avenues than just vote-to-close.  If nothing else, a comment can be left for other reviewers/readers to consider, or to gently remind/notify the OP about the potential issue.

This. And it's often a matter of applying a bit of tolerance and trying to gauge what the asker actually wants: sometimes they really just want to know what chip to buy and don't want to learn what the design process in solving some problem is. If the rest of the question indicates that, then "curing" the question would require asking a different question than what was meant to be asked. But sometimes, commenting something like "hey, I removed your what chip do I need to buy to… and replaced it with how do I approach a circuit design that does…, because {close reasons}" is very feasible.

The question essentially asks for IC's or an IC that can preform that task. I suppose that you could reword this easily and ask for a circuit design.
The OP isn't quite clear on what they want and there isn't any timing on waveform so coming up with a circuit to do this might be a challange.

Oh I see now how "IC" could be understood to be asking for a specific part number. I intuitively interpreted it as (manufacturer agnostic) glue logic, due to OP ruling out programmable logic.

Glad that was clarified :)

Regarding "not VTC": incidentally, the action log shows (at time of writing) "7hr | left closed | Voltage Spike" and then "4hr | edited | Voltage Spike" and "4hr | reopened | Voltage Spike" (and others).  I've seen this a few times, where it looks like a question was closed and immediately reopened; I assume this is just a quirk of the system, e.g. easier to clear close votes by passing then immediately reopening, something like that?
